# gcc undefined reference with reference paths defined in makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker, arm, undefined-reference

I am learning GCC and have some undefined reference errors when running make. I am using a makefile which I did not create, however while troubleshooting these undefined reference errors I went through each line of the makefile to understand what is happening and try to fix the problem but haven't been successful although I did learn a lot about the syntax used in the makefile.

Here is the undefined reference output when using make:

```
/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -g -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb  -I/home/np/STMBook -I/home/np/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Lib_V3.5.0/Libraries/CMSIS/CM3/DeviceSupport/ST/STM32F10x -I/home/np/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Lib_V3.5.0/Libraries/CMSIS/CM3/CoreSupport -I/home/np/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Lib_V3.5.0/Libraries/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Driver/inc -I. -DSTM32F10X_MD_VL  -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT  -I/home/np/STMBook/Library/ff9/src -I/home/np/STMBook/Library  -T/home/np/STMBook/stm32f100.ld -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3   BlinkLight.c   -o BlinkLight
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol Reset_Handler; defaulting to 08000000
/tmp/ccZbJmMi.o: In function `main':
/home/np/STMBook/BlinkLight.c:11: undefined reference to `RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd'
/home/np/STMBook/BlinkLight.c:14: undefined reference to `GPIO_StructInit'
/home/np/STMBook/BlinkLight.c:18: undefined reference to `GPIO_Init'
/home/np/STMBook/BlinkLight.c:21: undefined reference to `SystemCoreClock'
/home/np/STMBook/BlinkLight.c:21: undefined reference to `SystemCoreClock'
/home/np/STMBook/BlinkLight.c:30: undefined reference to `GPIO_WriteBit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [BlinkLight] Error 1
```

And here is my makefile which has two parts:

Part 1:

```
TEMPLATEROOT = /home/np/STMBook

# compilation flags for gdb

CFLAGS  += -O0 -g
ASFLAGS += -g

# object files

OBJS=   $(STARTUP) BlinkLight.o 
OBJS+=  stm32f10x_gpio.o stm32f10x_rcc.o

# include common make file

include $(TEMPLATEROOT)/Makefile.common
```

Part 2 (makefile.common):

```
# name of executable

ELF=$(notdir $(CURDIR)).elf                    

# Tool path

TOOLROOT=/usr/bin

# Library path    

LIBROOT=/home/np/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Lib_V3.5.0

# Tools      

CC=$(TOOLROOT)/arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD=$(TOOLROOT)/arm-none-eabi-gcc
AR=$(TOOLROOT)/arm-none-eabi-ar
AS=$(TOOLROOT)/arm-none-eabi-as

# Code Paths

DEVICE=$(LIBROOT)/Libraries/CMSIS/CM3/DeviceSupport/ST/STM32F10x
CORE=$(LIBROOT)/Libraries/CMSIS/CM3/CoreSupport
PERIPH=$(LIBROOT)/Libraries/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Driver

# Search path for standard files

vpath %.c $(TEMPLATEROOT)

# Search path for perpheral library

vpath %.c $(CORE)
vpath %.c $(PERIPH)/src
vpath %.c $(DEVICE)

# Search path for Library

vpath %.c $(TEMPLATEROOT)/Library/ff9/src
vpath %.c $(TEMPLATEROOT)/Library/ff9/src/option
vpath %.c $(TEMPLATEROOT)/Library

#  Processor specific

PTYPE = STM32F10X_MD_VL 
LDSCRIPT = $(TEMPLATEROOT)/stm32f100.ld
STARTUP= startup_stm32f10x.o system_stm32f10x.o 

# Compilation Flags

FULLASSERT = -DUSE_FULL_ASSERT 

LDFLAGS+= -T$(LDSCRIPT) -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 
CFLAGS+= -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb 
CFLAGS+= -I$(TEMPLATEROOT) -I$(DEVICE) -I$(CORE) -I$(PERIPH)/inc -I.
CFLAGS+= -D$(PTYPE) -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER $(FULLASSERT)
CFLAGS+= -I$(TEMPLATEROOT)/Library/ff9/src -I$(TEMPLATEROOT)/Library

# Build executable 

$(ELF) : $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

# compile and generate dependency info

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) $< > $*.d

%.o: %.s
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d) $(ELF) startup_stm32f* $(CLEANOTHER)

debug: $(ELF)
    arm-none-eabi-gdb $(ELF)


# pull in dependencies

    -include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

Here is my understanding:

The undefined references are contained in files stm32f10x_gpio.c (GPIO undefined references) and stm32f10x_rcc.c (RCC undefined reference) and these are declared as required objects in the OBJS variable in Part 1 of the makefile:

```
OBJS=   $(STARTUP) BlinkLight.o 
OBJS+=  stm32f10x_gpio.o stm32f10x_rcc.o
```

Undefined reference 'SystemCoreClock' is located in system_stm32f10x.c file in the directory given in the makefile as:

```
STARTUP= startup_stm32f10x.o system_stm32f10x.o
```

and is included in the OBJS variable.

The path to the .c files for compiling the required objects are defined in the makefile:

Location of stm32f10x_gpio.c and stm32f10x_rcc.c:

```
vpath %.c $(PERIPH)/src
```

Location of system_stm32f10x.c:

```
vpath %.c $(DEVICE)
```

All of the required objects which contain the undefined references are passed to the target build instructions as variable OBJS:

```
$(ELF) : $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)
```

Also included in the makefile is build instructions on how to obtain the object files from the C source files:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) $< > $*.d
```

I do not understand why it seems to be that the C source files cannot be found. Thank you for any suggestions, I really appreciate any help.

Sorry for my post being so long, I tried to go through each line of the makefile and research all the symbols and syntax to figure out the problem on my own and went through many of the undefined reference questions on this site but have not figured it out.

Comment: I don't know what stage you are in but first error is linking error and I'm not sure if you are really linking. rules are set to create .o from .c but in the error triggering command you can see it is actually trying to create BlinkLight without .o part, which is missing "-c" as well. so those are your hints.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. After reading your comment and looking back over my code I think I may see the problem. I am using command 'make BlinkLight' and I have the BlinkLight.c file in my current directory. But in the makefile, the target name is defined based on the variable 'ELF' which is based on the current directory name. Therefore I think I need to change my BlinkLight.C file name to the name of the directory which would be STMBook.C. If I change the name to STMBook.C then I can use 'Make STMBook' and it should be able to use the rule which is defined in the makefile.